# elips macro that return's the current file's filename

Tags: elisp-macros

I want to define a action that says `open <config file>` within the actual config file itself. However, this config file may be in a different location on different computers. How can I get the current file's filename with a macro?

---

In this [example](https://github.com/zcaudate/etude/blob/master/etude/module/etude-module-lisp.el#L16), I'm looking avoid typing `"etude-module-lisp"` or the filename of the file in this particular piece of code:

```
(on/mode: [::lisp   lisp-interaction-mode]
  "etude-module-lisp"
  ::eval-cursor    'eval-last-sexp
  ::eval-buffer    'eval-buffer)
```

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what you're asking. Are you looking for a keyboard macro or a Lisp macro (why)? What is that "action" (doesn't look like Lisp). How would you define it normally, e.g. without Emacs? And what do you mean by the current file - do you mean the file visited by the `current-buffer`? (If so, use function `buffer-file-name`.)

Comment: Apparently this is about determining a namespace/module equivalent at compilation time. This kind of thing can be done easily in Clojure, in Emacs Lisp, not so much.

Comment: I think you're looking for `load-file-name`, but I'm not sure how that macro is supposed to work.

Comment: @npostavs. this works. it's not a macro. it's a variable that's set automatically when the file is compiled. I'll accept your answer if you write it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the variable `load-file-name` for this.  Note that it's only bound while your file is loading.  So this doesn't work (because you finished loading `foo.el` or `foo.elc` before `foo-function` is called):

```el
(defun foo-function ()
  (message "loaded from %s" load-file-name))
```

You should save the value when the file is being loaded, e.g.:

```el
(defconst foo-file (or load-file-name buffer-file-name))

(defun foo-function ()
  (message "loaded from %s" foo-file))
```

Falling back to `buffer-file-name` lets it work with `eval-buffer` as well as `load`.